# ZeroConf extension that can be used in Firefox/XULRunner?

Tags: firefox, xulrunner, zeroconf, mdns, slp

Is there a [ZeroConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZeroConf) client extension for Firefox/XULRunner to be used in a zeroConf environment based on either [mDNS](http://files.multicastdns.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-multicastdns.txt) or [SLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Location_Protocol)?

I know of an extension already that's being developed by the [ActiveState Open Komodo](http://svn.openkomodo.com/openkomodo/browse/addons/sdconnector/) folks but it requires PyXPCOM support to be baked into the XULRunner runtime in order to access the Apple [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/networking/bonjour/download/) libs for Windows. Is there anything else available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Andrew Tunnell-Jones has undertaken the task.

http://andrew.tj.id.au/projects/bonjourfoxy/

I have not yet verified that it works for me under Windows, but I am hopeful :)

It did not discover that I activated web sharing here, only with a user account active.  Let me know what you find.

Answer (score 1):

[BonjourFoxy](http://www.bonjourfoxy.net/) has come some way since Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen's post. It's implemented as a set of binary XPCOM modules tied together with a JavaScript XPCOM service. The service can be used to register, browse and resolve services as well as to enumerate browse and registrations domains. It builds and runs on OS X 10.5 (Intel), Ubuntu 8.10 (32-bit) and Windows XP (32-bit) and has been run on Windows 2000 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The links given in this answer are dead or misleading.
It seems like the project has changed its name and can now be found at
http://dnssd.me/ .

I can confirm it works on

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0` on Win7.

I would have commented the posts, but don't have enough reputation to do so.